# preg_match wildcard, require at least one character

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

The preg_match below matches 'empty' (0 characters) against the wildcard. I want to disable that:

```
preg_match('/site.com\/subsection\/.*?/', $page_url);
```

So the thing above should match site.com/subsection/subpage, but shouldn't match the root dir site.com/subsection/

How can I adjust the regex above? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `'/site\.com\/subsection\/.+/'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.*?` at the end of the pattern matches empty string. You need to make it match one or more characters using `.+`:

```
'/site\.com\/subsection\/.+/'
                         ^
```

Now, it requires at least 1 char after `site.com/subsection/`.

Note the dot must be escaped to match a literal dot.

Also, it might be a good idea to use regex delimiters other than `/` (as [OcuS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/248343/ocus) suggests in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40788865/preg-match-wildcard-require-at-least-one-character/40788917?noredirect=1#comment68800206_40788917) below) if you have many slashes in the pattern itself. I usually use tildes:

```
'~site\.com/subsection/.+~'
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work! Will accept your answer when allowed.

Comment: And save yourself some chars by choosing a different delimiter instead of `/`. Something like `@site\.com/subsection/.+@`. It also adds more readability IMHO.